# Как в Pandas убрать экспоненциальное представление чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Вывожу DataFrame и почему-то некоторые числа выводятся в экспоненциальном виде. Они не маленькие, обычные - например 1604 выводится как 1.604000e+03.
Как поправить это?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Так, проблема была в том, что выводилось слишком много цифр после запятой.
Я просто применил к каждому столбцу `map(lambda x: round(x, 3))`